# Как получить дату из строки?

Tags: php

Есть дата взятая с ютуба 2017-01-21T02:57:01.000Z
Как преобразовать её в обычную дату?

Comment: В каком формате вам нужно? обычная дата бывает по разному...

Comment: В php есть класс Date

Answer (score 1):

Очень просто `echo (new \DateTime('2017-01-21T02:57:01.000Z'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` 
Я предположил, что "обычная" дата для вас имеет вид `2017-01-21 02:57:01`

Comment: $date = new \DateTime('2017-01-21T02:57:01.000Z');
    $list_youtube[$key]['date'] = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');  так можно

Comment: А я так делаю и оно так работает. PHP 7.0 И тоже с API ютуба работаю. Возможно, ваша версия PHP не позволяет такие конструкции. Тогда да, дату выносите в отдельный объект, а потом вызывайте format.